# Javascript Price Calculator Issues

Tags: javascript, html

I have attempted a few times to create a price calculator, however the price is never displayed at the end, as it should be. Im still new to Javascript so I am unsure if something is coded incorrectly. I believe I understand it enough to see that it SHOULD appear, but maybe someone here may see something I have done wrong in my code?

```js
var eventDurationArray = new Array();
eventDurationArray["2hrs"]=120;
eventDurationArray["3hrs"]=180;
eventDurationArray["4hrs"]=240;
eventDurationArray["5hrs"]=300;
eventDurationArray["6hrs"]=360;

//RADIO BUTTON - EVENT DURATION TEST
function getEventDuration() {
  var EventDuration = 0;

  var theForm = document.forms["#quote"];

  var selectedEventDuration = theForm.elements["selectedDuration"];

  for(var i = 0; i < selectedDuration.length; i++)
  {
    if(selectedDuration[i].checked)
    {
      EventDuration = eventDurationArray[selectedDuration[i].value];

      break;
    }
  }

  return EventDuration;
}

//DIV - TOTAL PRICE TEST
function getTotals() {
  var totalPrice = getEventDuration();
  var totalPriceDIV = document.getElementById("#totalPrice");
  totalPriceDIV.innerHTML = "Total: $"+totalPrice;
}
```

```html
<form id="quote" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
  <input type="radio"  name="selectedDuration" value="2hrs" onclick="getTotals()" />
  Round cake 6" -  serves 8 people ($20)
  <input type="radio"  name="selectedDuration" value="3hrs" onclick="getTotals()" />
  Round cake 8" - serves 12 people ($25)
  <input type="radio"  name="selectedDuration" value="4hrs" onclick="getTotals()" />
  Round cake 10" - serves 16 people($35)
  <input type="radio"  name="selectedDuration" value="5hrs" onclick="getTotals()" />
  Round cake 12" - serves 30 people($75)
  <br />
  <br />
  <div id="totalPrice" style="color: red; text-align: center; font-size: 18px;"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some problems in your code..

1. `document.forms["quote"]` - remove the `#` and set `name` attribute instead of `id`.
2. Change `var selectedEventDuration` to `var selectedDuration = theForm.elements["selectedDuration"];`
3. Remove the `#` from `nt.getElementById("#totalPrice");`

```js
var eventDurationArray = new Array();
eventDurationArray["2hrs"]=120;
eventDurationArray["3hrs"]=180;
eventDurationArray["4hrs"]=240;
eventDurationArray["5hrs"]=300;
eventDurationArray["6hrs"]=360;

//RADIO BUTTON - EVENT DURATION TEST
function getEventDuration() {
  var EventDuration = 0;

  var theForm = document.forms["quote"];

  var selectedDuration = theForm.elements["selectedDuration"];

  for(var i = 0; i < selectedDuration.length; i++)
  {
    if(selectedDuration[i].checked)
    {
      EventDuration = eventDurationArray[selectedDuration[i].value];

      break;
    }
  }

  return EventDuration;
}

//DIV - TOTAL PRICE TEST
function getTotals() {
  var totalPrice = getEventDuration();
  var totalPriceDIV = document.getElementById("totalPrice");
  totalPriceDIV.innerHTML = "Total: $"+totalPrice;
}
```

```html
<form name="quote" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
  <input type="radio"  name="selectedDuration" value="2hrs" onclick="getTotals()" />
  Round cake 6" -  serves 8 people ($20)
  <input type="radio"  name="selectedDuration" value="3hrs" onclick="getTotals()" />
  Round cake 8" - serves 12 people ($25)
  <input type="radio"  name="selectedDuration" value="4hrs" onclick="getTotals()" />
  Round cake 10" - serves 16 people($35)
  <input type="radio"  name="selectedDuration" value="5hrs" onclick="getTotals()" />
  Round cake 12" - serves 30 people($75)
  <br />
  <br />
  <div id="totalPrice" style="color: red; text-align: center; font-size: 18px;"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks Mosh :)

Comment: Silly thing wont let me accept an answer for another 5 minutes? Weird system haha Cheers! ( And upvoted ;) )

Comment: I'd hate to be a pain, but I have recently tried adding a checkbox with equipment into the calculations, however it doesnt seem to change the price depending on the selected checkboxes. Any idea where I am going wrong?

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/dqx5yLz7/

Comment: When you have a code that does not work, first thing is to look at the `console`. You have an error there: `getEventDuration is not defined` where do you defined this function?

Comment: That function is set earlier in the code. I believe it is set in my original code above?

Comment: Here is the recent question I have asked:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35452000/javascript-price-calculator-issues-checkboxes?noredirect=1#comment58600808_35452000

Comment: OK.. It's seems that I got answers. Isn't?

Comment: Yeah, a few answers there worked perfectly haha Thanks for the reply though! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have solve minor issue in your javascript as per below it will help to you.

```
function getEventDuration() {
    var EventDuration = 0;
    var theForm = document.forms["quote"];
    var selectedEventDuration = theForm.elements["selectedDuration"];
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedEventDuration.length; i++) {
        if (selectedEventDuration[i].checked) {
            EventDuration = eventDurationArray[selectedEventDuration[i].value];
            break;
        }
    }
    return EventDuration;
}
//DIV - TOTAL PRICE TEST
function getTotals() {
    var totalPrice = getEventDuration();

    var totalPriceDIV = document.getElementById("totalPrice");

    totalPriceDIV.innerHTML = "Total: $" + totalPrice;
}
```

**Information :-**  # is indicator for jquery element so when you use only javascript then it is not required.

Comment: Thank you for the help Pragnesh! I will keep that in mind for future scripts :)

Answer (score 1):

Change `document.getElementById("#totalPrice");` with `document.getElementById("totalPrice");`

Answer (score 1):

Opening the inspector on your code sample, shows that `elements` is undefined.

I would recommend using `document.querySelector` to find the active radio button.

`EventDuration = document.querySelector("input[name= selectedDuration]:checked").value`

Furthermore, `getElementById` expects just an id, with no `#`. Again, I tend to stick to `document.querySelector` for everything, keeps things simple.

Comment: Thanks for that mcfedr. I have achieved the result I was looking for by Mosh Feu, however I may look into using .querySelector in the near future and see how that works out for me! Thanks for the help.

Comment: I find it give a much more modern way to interact with the DOM, close to the functionality of jQuery, but without all the overheads of that, and better than navigating all the other stuff via `document`

Comment: Hmm, it certainly seems like something I would consider. Seems to be not too difficult to understand. Food for thought. Might start Googling some of that .querySelector stuff and see how it works haha. Cheers!