# Javascript Price Calculator Issues (Checkboxes)

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a bit of trouble making the checkboxes display their values when checked and removing their value when unchecked. Before this I added a drop-down menu and radio buttons with values for a quote form. I have now added this checkbox group with values, however when the total amount is added at the end in the "totalPrice" DIV, it doesnt add in the checked boxes for the Equipment. Below is the Javascript and HTML code:

```
<script>
//ARRAY
var eventEquipmentArray = new Array();
eventEquipmentArray["15 Inch Speakers"]=5;
eventEquipmentArray["18 Inch Subwoofer"]=10;
eventEquipmentArray["LED Par Cans"]=5;
eventEquipmentArray["Smoke Machine"]=5;
eventEquipmentArray["Moving Head"]=10;
eventEquipmentArray["4 Gun Laser System"]=5;
eventEquipmentArray["Red Gun Laser System"]=5;
eventEquipmentArray["1500W Strobes"]=10;
eventEquipmentArray["Mirror LED Lighting"]=5;

//CHECKBOX - EVENT EQUIPMENT
function getEventEquipment()
{
    var EventEquipment = 0;

    var theForm = document.forms["quote"];

    var selectedEquipment = theForm.elements["selectedEquipment"];

    for(var i = 0; i < selectedEquipment.length; i++)
    {
        EventEquipment = EventEquipment + eventEquipmentArray[selectedEquipment[i].value];

        break;
    }

    return EventEquipment;

}

//DIV - TOTAL PRICE TEST
function getTotals()
{
    var totalPrice = getEventDuration() + getEventSuburb() + getEventEquipment();

    var totalPriceDIV = document.getElementById("totalPrice");

    totalPriceDIV.innerHTML = "Total: $"+totalPrice;
}
</script>

<form id="quote" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
<p>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedEquipment" value="15 Inch Speakers" id="selectedEquipment_0" onChange="getTotals()" />
        15" Speakers</label>
      <br />
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedEquipment" value="18 Inch Subwoofer" id="selectedEquipment_1" onChange="getTotals()" />
        18" Subwoofer</label>
      <br />
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedEquipment" value="LED Par Cans" id="selectedEquipment_2" onChange="getTotals()" />
        LED Par Cans</label>
      <br />
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedEquipment" value="Smoke Machine" id="selectedEquipment_3" onChange="getTotals()" />
        Smoke Machine</label>
      <br />
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedEquipment" value="250W Moving Head" id="selectedEquipment_4" onChange="getTotals()" />
        250W Moving Head</label>
      <br />
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedEquipment" value="Mirror LED Lighting" id="selectedEquipment_5" onChange="getTotals()" />
        Mirror LED Lights</label>
      <br />
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedEquipment" value="4 Gun Laser System" id="selectedEquipment_6" onChange="getTotals()" />
        4 Gun Laser Light</label>
      <br />
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedEquipment" value="Red Gun Laser System" id="selectedEquipment_7" onChange="getTotals()" />
        Red Laser Star Light</label>
      <br />
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedEquipment" value="1500W Strobes" id="selectedEquipment_8" onChange="getTotals()" />
        1500W Strobes</label>
      <br />
    </p>
  <br />

  <div id="totalPrice" style="color: red; text-align: center; font-size: 18px;"></div>
</form>
```

I have all the information of the Javascript and HTML placed in a JSFiddle below:
https://jsfiddle.net/dqx5yLz7/

Comment: What is your problem exactly? What isnt working, what errors do you see?

Comment: Before this I added a drop-down menu and radio buttons with values for a quote form. I have now added this checkbox group with values, however when the total amount is added at the end in the "totalPrice" DIV, it doesnt add in the checked boxes for the Equipment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove break inside `for`. This will only return 1st value.

Second, you can use `element.checked` to check if its checked and add its value.

Third, you are accessing `document.forms["quote"];`, but there is no form with id `quote`

Also `getEventDuration()`, `getEventSuburb()` these functions are missing in your fiddle. I'm assuming that they were not relevant for current scenario and have commented them.

You can try something like this:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/dqx5yLz7/1/).

```js
//ARRAY
var eventEquipmentArray = new Array();
eventEquipmentArray["15 Inch Speakers"] = 5;
eventEquipmentArray["18 Inch Subwoofer"] = 10;
eventEquipmentArray["LED Par Cans"] = 5;
eventEquipmentArray["Smoke Machine"] = 5;
eventEquipmentArray["Moving Head"] = 10;
eventEquipmentArray["4 Gun Laser System"] = 5;
eventEquipmentArray["Red Gun Laser System"] = 5;
eventEquipmentArray["1500W Strobes"] = 10;
eventEquipmentArray["Mirror LED Lighting"] = 5;

//CHECKBOX - EVENT EQUIPMENT
function getEventEquipment() {
  var EventEquipment = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["quote"];
  var selectedEquipment = theForm.elements["selectedEquipment"];

  for (var i = 0; i < selectedEquipment.length; i++) {
   if(selectedEquipment[i].checked){
     EventEquipment += eventEquipmentArray[selectedEquipment[i].value] || 0;
    }
  }

  return EventEquipment;
}

//DIV - TOTAL PRICE TEST
function getTotals() {
  //var totalPrice = getEventDuration() + getEventSuburb() + getEventEquipment();
  var totalPrice = getEventEquipment();
  var totalPriceDIV = document.getElementById("totalPrice");
  totalPriceDIV.innerText = "Total: $ " + totalPrice;
}
```

```html
<form id="quote">
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="selectedEquipment" value="15 Inch Speakers" id="selectedEquipment_0" onChange="getTotals()" /> 15" Speakers</label>
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="selectedEquipment" value="18 Inch Subwoofer" id="selectedEquipment_1" onChange="getTotals()" /> 18" Subwoofer</label>
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="selectedEquipment" value="LED Par Cans" id="selectedEquipment_2" onChange="getTotals()" /> LED Par Cans</label>
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="selectedEquipment" value="Smoke Machine" id="selectedEquipment_3" onChange="getTotals()" /> Smoke Machine</label>
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="selectedEquipment" value="250W Moving Head" id="selectedEquipment_4" onChange="getTotals()" /> 250W Moving Head</label>
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="selectedEquipment" value="Mirror LED Lighting" id="selectedEquipment_5" onChange="getTotals()" /> Mirror LED Lights</label>
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="selectedEquipment" value="4 Gun Laser System" id="selectedEquipment_6" onChange="getTotals()" /> 4 Gun Laser Light</label>
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="selectedEquipment" value="Red Gun Laser System" id="selectedEquipment_7" onChange="getTotals()" /> Red Laser Star Light</label>
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="selectedEquipment" value="1500W Strobes" id="selectedEquipment_8" onChange="getTotals()" /> 1500W Strobes</label>
    <br />
  </p>

  <div id="totalPrice" style="color: red; text-align: center; font-size: 18px;"></div>

</form>
```

Comment: I have tried your reply and it seems to work a charm! However, could you please explain how that script works? I am trying to learn as I go and knowing how that little bit of script worked would help heaps!

Comment: Can you be specific about which part did you not understand?

Comment: Could you explain the script inside the for loop please? :)

Comment: `if(selectedEquipment[i].checked)` will check if checkbox is checked or not. It will return `true` or `false`(default). If it is checked then if satisfies condition and proceeds in it. `eventEquipmentArray[selectedEquipment[i].value]` will fetch value from array that you have created. So if value is `15 Inch Speakers`, its like `eventEquipmentArray["15 Inch Speakers"]` which is `5`

Comment: Awesome! Makes sense :) So what does the " || 0;" at the end do?

Comment: Now `+=` is a short hand. `i = i + something` is same as `i += something`. Also `|| 0`, is a short hand to check if first value is available and not falsy and if not, it will return second value. So for cases where you do not have key in array, instead of undefined, return `0`. Like `250W Moving Head ` is not available in array and will return undefined. So 0 is preferred here

Answer (score 1):

i have jQuery solution for your problem i hope it helps.

```js
$(".checkbox").click(function(){
    var favorite = [];
    $.each($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked'), function() {
      favorite.push($(this).val());
      console.log(favorite);
    });

    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < favorite.length; i++) {
      total += favorite[i] << 0;
    }
    $('#total').html(total);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="submit">18 Inch Subwoofer</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input id="checkbox" name="Subwoofer" realname="18 Inch Subwoofer" type="checkbox" value="10"/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label for="submit">LED Par Cans</label>
  <div>
    <input id="checkbox" name="LED" type="checkbox" realname="LED Par Cans" value="5"/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label for="submit">Smoke Machine</label>
  <div >
    <input id="checkbox" name="Smoke Machine" realname="Smoke Machine"type="checkbox" value="5"/>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <label for="name">Totalprice: </label>
 
    <p id="total"></p>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply MKAD! I have not tried your way, instead opting to use another answer, however I thank you for your reply. Im sure if I use jQuery for my next quote form, I will refer back to this answer for some help! :)

Answer (score 1):

In the function `getEventEquipment()` inside the for loop you need to add the condition to check whether the check box is selected or not and remove the break statement. The altered code is below :

```
function getEventEquipment()
 {
     var EventEquipment = 0;

     var theForm = document.forms["quote"];

     var selectedEquipment = theForm.elements["selectedEquipment"];

     for(var i = 0; i < selectedEquipment.length; i++)
     {
         if (selectedEquipment[i].checked) {
             EventEquipment = parseInt(EventEquipment, 10) + parseInt(eventEquipmentArray[selectedEquipment[i].value], 10);
         }

     }

     return EventEquipment;

 }
```

Also make sure the form's id has been set to `quote`.

If you get NaN in the count please check your array and the value details in the form.

Comment: Your reply has answered my question, however I am unsure of how the "(EventEquipment, 10)" work? Could you please explain how this works for future reference?

Comment: we are just trying to convert it to int.. sometime insted of adding the values will get appened.. so only we are converting to int before doing any mathematical operation. for that parseInt() function you can refer the below link..

[http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp]